# Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable is wiping the Session with every refresh?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, zend-session

I'm basically encountering the same problem as the poster in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638145/storing-sessions-in-db-table-not-working-using-zend-session-savehandler-dbtable).  My database is initialized properly.  I've tried doing the initialization of both the database and the session SaveHandler in the `application.ini` and in the `Bootstrap`.  Same result no matter how I do it.

Here's what the `application.ini` initialization looks like:

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "uname"
resources.db.params.password = "******"
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"

resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "sessions"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary = "sessionID"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "lastModifiedTime"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"
```

And here's what the Bootstrap initialization looked like:

```
protected function _initSession() {
        $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
            'host'        =>'localhost',
            'username'    => 'uname',
            'password'    => '******',
            'dbname'    => 'dbname'
        ));
        Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);


    $sessionConfig = array( 
            'name'           => 'sessions',      
            'primary'        => 'sessionID',   
            'modifiedColumn' => 'lastModifiedTime',     
            'dataColumn'     => 'data',
            'lifetimeColumn' => 'lifetime'
        ); 
        $saveHandler = new Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable($sessionConfig); 
        Zend_Session::setSaveHandler($saveHandler); 
        Zend_Session::start();

}
```

My sessions database table is defined as follows:

```
create table sesssions (
    sessionID char(32) primary key not null, 
    lastModifiedTime timestamp, 
    lifetime timestamp, 
    data text
) engine=innodb;
```

I have a test action that tests this through a very simple one field form that just dumps its contents into the Session.  The action looks like this:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();

    $form = new Application_Form_AddToSession();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
           $namespace->content = $request->getParam('toAdd');
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form; 
}
```

Here's the form it uses:

```
class Application_Form_AddToSession extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement('text', 'toAdd', array(
            'filters'    => array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'),
            'validators' => array(
                array('StringLength', false, array(0, 256)),
            ),
            'required'   => true,
            'label'      => 'Add:',
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'add', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Add',
        )); 
    }


}
```

The view just shows the form.

To test whether or not the value actually went into the session, I use the index action.  This is the index action in question:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $namespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
    echo 'Content: '.$namespace->content.'<br>';
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); echo '</pre>';
}
```

Now.  If I don't have Session saving configured to use `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable`, ie, if I don't have session saving configured at all, then this works fine.  I enter a value in the form field, go to the index action and have it output back to me.  Session works exactly the way it is supposed to.

If I have `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` configured in either the `application.ini` or the Bootstrap, then when I enter a value into the test field and go to the index action the value is gone.  My database table has a row with the proper `sessionID` and the `sessionID` matches a cookie in my browser.  But there is no other information in the database.  `data` is NULL and both the `TIMESTAMP` fields are zeroed out.

I've run out of things to try.  I've had the Mysql table as a regular table and an InnoDB table.  I've tried every permutation of the database and session configuration I can come up with, including giving the db to the configuration array, and initializing one in the Bootstrap and the other in the `.ini`.  I've scoured the web and StackOverflow for clues.  I've seen other people post about similar problems, but none of the answers I've found have worked.  What haven't I done?  What have I screwed up?  How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you defined lastModifiedTime and lifetime columns as timestamp. They should be INT instead:

```
CREATE TABLE  `sessions` (
`sessionID` char(32) NOT NULL,
`lastModifiedTime` INT,
`lifetime` INT,
`data` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`sessionID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After this small modification it should work.

Comment: I'd just add that it's strange to have the config in INI and then never use it in the actual init method. May lead to strange behaviour in future (as you forget how it's implemented, or someone else will be using it)